# what could be the meaning of "welcome addenda"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What could be the meaning (or a simple English explanation) of **`welcome addenda`** in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamanism) context or in any other? The dictionary defines "addenda" as  "textual matter that is added onto a publication; usually at the end", which doesn't seem to apply to "goods".

> An account states that the gifts and payments that a shaman receives are given by his partner spirit. Since it obliges the shaman to use his gift and to work regularly in this capacity, the spirit rewards him with the goods that it receives.[60] These goods, however, are only "**welcome addenda**". They are not enough to enable a full-time shaman. Shamans live like any other member of the group, as a hunter or housewife.

Comment: I've remove the translation request. ... Have you checked addenda in you dictionary? What does it mean?

Comment: @JamesK, That's an EDIT; Thank you. I did check! I found this: "`textual matter that is added onto a publication; usually at the end`"

Answer (score 1):

An [addendum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/addendum) is normally

> extra information added at the end of a report, letter, contract, etc.

It therefore does not fit comfortably into the text that you provided, as ithe text refers to goods, not information. It would be better written as "welcome additions".

In this context, [welcome](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/welcome) means

> If something is welcome, you are pleased to have or do it

I think that the writer is trying to say that the gifts and payments that the shaman receives are not enough to live on, but the shaman is **pleased** to receive them as an **addition** to their normal income.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuu, is there any reference?

Comment: @elyarabad: reference? I have provided links to definition of welcome and addendum, and explained that this is not a conventional usage of the word addendum. What other reference could I provide?

Comment: I really appreciate you help; however, academically, a reference is needed to support `writer is trying to say that the gifts and payments that the shaman receives are not enough to live on, but the shaman is pleased to receive them as an addition to their normal income.`.

Comment: @elyarabad, This is my guess at the interpretation of a **misuse** of a word: you will not find any references to support this misuse. If you really need a reference, I suggest that you contact the original author and ask them to rephrase that paragraph.

Comment: That will, certainly, obtain an admit-table result for me; I'll check that and reflect the response here . . . THANK YOU . . .